# Framing theorem and proof together

Tags: theorems, mdframed

#### What I want to do

I'm trying to frame a theorem and its proof like this:

[image]

#### How I currently do it

The image above was produced by the code below:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoloredbox}{mm}{
\newmdenv[
  roundcorner=4pt,
  leftline=true,
  rightline=true, 
  bottomline=true,
  topline=true,
  innertopmargin=7pt,
  linecolor=black,
  linewidth=1,
  backgroundcolor=#2,
]{#1}
}

\newcoloredbox{theorembox}{green!20}
\newcoloredbox{proofbox}{white}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
  {0pt}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {\thmnote{#3}. \hfill \thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem_}[equation]{Theorem}

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]
{
  \begin{theorembox}
  \begin{theorem_}[#1] \leavevmode \\ \noindent
}
{
  \end{theorem_}
  \end{theorembox}
}

\newenvironment{fproof}[1][]
{
  \vspace{-1.8em}
  \begin{proofbox}
  #1
}
{
  \hfill \qedsymbol
  \end{proofbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some nice theorem]
Some extraordinary claim.
\end{theorem}

\begin{fproof}
Some unconvincing proof.
\begin{equation}
x + y = 1.
\end{equation}
\end{fproof}

\end{document}
```

#### Problems

There are a couple of problems with the above approach:

1. The proof-box is moved in contact with the theorem-box simply by using a negative space `\vspace{-1.8em}` in the `fproof` environment. I found that value experimentally. Sometimes the proof-box and theorem-box overlap, which is not intended.
2. The "Theorem 1" on the right does not align together with the equation marker (2). I would like them to be aligned from the right.

These problems are perhaps better seen from the following image:

[image]

#### Question

How can I achieve what I want to do in a robust way?

Comment: The problem 2 seems to be fixed by replacing `{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}` with `{0pt}`. Not sure why I had it in the first place.

Comment: I know this won't help you solve your problem, but I wonder if your arrangement is to much eye candy. As a mathematician, I think I would prefer to read the same theorems on a quieter page. Mathematics is a calm, quiet and thoughtful endeavor.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay This is something new I'm trying, so I'm not sure whether to keep it. I like boxes because they quickly show where the proof or theorem ends, so that you can skip it if you already read it, or don't want to read it. I have red for counterexamples, blue for notes, gray for definitions. Do you object to colors, or to frames?

Comment: I am not sure what I am objecting to. I can appreciate that it might help to see where the proof ends more clearly than the usual presentation. Maybe the colour is too much for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two options with `tcolorbox` using the `environment upper args` option to wrap the theorem in a tcolorbox. The first option integrates the theorem and proof in one environment, separated by `\tcblower`. The second uses two separate environments for the theorem and proof. Note that I moved the period into `\thmnote` so that if no title is given to the theorem, the period is not printed.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
  {0pt}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {\thmnote{#3.}\hfill\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\newline}

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtcolorbox{boxtheorem}[1][]{
  environment upper args={theorem}{[#1]},
  after lower=\qed,
  bicolor,
  colback=green!20,
  colbacklower=white,
  }
\newtcolorbox{boxtheoremnoproof}[1][]{
  environment upper args={theorem}{[#1]},
  colback=green!20,
  after skip=0pt,
  }
\newtcolorbox{boxproof}{
  before skip=0pt,
  colback=white,
  after upper=\qed
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{boxtheorem}[Some nice theorem]
Some extraordinary claim.
\tcblower
Some unconvincing proof.
\begin{equation}
  x+y=1
\end{equation}
\end{boxtheorem}

\begin{boxtheoremnoproof}
Another extraordinary claim.
\end{boxtheoremnoproof}

\begin{boxproof}
Another unconvincing proof.
\begin{equation}
  x+y=1
\end{equation}
\end{boxproof}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this as follows:

- Problem 1: Use `skipabove` and `skipbelow` arguments of `mdframed` to set theorem's `skipbelow` and proof's `skipabove` to 0pt. This will place the boxes right after each other. To make the lines coincide, replace `\vspace{-1.8em}` with `\vspace{-1pt}` to match the width of the line.
- Problem 2: replace `{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}` with `{0pt}` in theorem definition.

[image]

The fixed code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcoloredbox}{mmO{1em}O{1em}}{
\newmdenv[
  roundcorner=4pt,
  leftline=true,
  rightline=true, 
  bottomline=true,
  topline=true,
  innertopmargin=7pt,
  linecolor=black,
  linewidth=1,
  backgroundcolor=#2,
  skipabove=#3,
  skipbelow=#4,
]{#1}
}

\newcoloredbox{theorembox}{green!20}[1em][0pt]
\newcoloredbox{proofbox}{white}[0pt][1em]

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
  {0pt}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\thmnote{#3}. \hfill \thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}

\newtheorem{theorem_}[equation]{Theorem}

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]
{
  \begin{theorembox}
  \begin{theorem_}[#1] \leavevmode \\ \noindent
}
{
  \end{theorem_}
  \end{theorembox}
}

\newenvironment{fproof}[1][]
{
  \vspace{-1pt}
  \begin{proofbox}
  #1
}
{
  \hfill \qedsymbol
  \end{proofbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some nice theorem]
Some extraordinary claim.
\end{theorem}

\begin{fproof}
Some unconvincing proof.
\begin{equation}
x + y = 1.
\end{equation}
\end{fproof}

\end{document}
```